# PHP: Parsing Huge Xml without memory

Tags: php, xml, parsing, memory

I would like to ask, if someone knows, if there is possibility to parse 500 MB xml.
The problem looks like that. I have huge xml file, which has few nodes (maybe not few, but comparing to one of the nodes, well it is))
One of the nodes is attachment node, which is base 64 encoded. There is possibility, that this node can be around 500 MB.

Now my question is there any possibility to decode it and write to a file without running out of memory on the server? Changing limit over 1GB is not resolutions here.

Well I was looking at xmlReader, but as far as I seen I can reach the node, which I would like to parse, but then I need to save the node into memory, well that's bad idea.
I need to append this node to file without reading it, but firstly I need to decode it.

To make it even funnier I will probably get such xml in parts, but I am planning to write parts to file one after another one. (Append it to the end of file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of XMLReader use [XML Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.xml.php). It allows you to parse xml by chunks, so it if very memory efficient. Here is working example, that looks for `<ATTACHMENT>` tags and decodes it's contents into file. Dealing with base64 is easy, just remember that it turns every 3 characters into 4 character encoded string, so as long as you are supplying chunks of length dividable by 4, you can concatenate decoded result.

```
<?php

class ExtractAttachments {

    private $parser;
    private $tmpFile;
    private $tmpHandle;
    private $buffer;

    private $files = array();

    public function __construct($xml) {
        $this->parser = xml_parser_create('UTF-8');
        xml_set_object($this->parser, $this);
        xml_set_element_handler($this->parser, 'tag_start', 'tag_end');
        xml_set_character_data_handler($this->parser, 'cdata');
        $handle = fopen($xml, 'rb');
        while($string = fread($handle, 4096)) {
            xml_parse($this->parser, $string, false);
        }
        xml_parse($this->parser, '', true);
        fclose($handle);
        xml_parser_free($this->parser);
    }

    public function tag_start($parser, $tag, $attr) {
        if($tag == 'ATTACHMENT') {
            $this->tmpFile = tempnam(__DIR__, 'xml');
            $this->tmpHandle = fopen($this->tmpFile, 'wb');
        }
    }

    public function tag_end($parser, $tag) {
        if($this->tmpHandle) {
            if($this->buffer) {
                fwrite($this->tmpHandle, base64_decode($this->buffer));
                $this->buffer = '';
            }
            fclose($this->tmpHandle);
            $this->tmpHandle = null;
            $this->files[] = $this->tmpFile;
        }
    }

    public function cdata($parser, $data) {
        if ($this->tmpHandle) {
            $data = trim($data);
            if($this->buffer) {
                $data = $this->buffer . $data;
                $this->buffer = '';
            }
            if (0 != ($modulo = strlen($data)%4)) {
                $this->buffer = substr($data, -$modulo);
                $data = substr($data, 0, -$modulo);
            }
            fwrite($this->tmpHandle, base64_decode($data));
        }
    }

    public function getFiles(){
        return $this->files;
    }
}

$xml = new ExtractAttachments('large.xml');
$xml->getFiles();
```

Comment: does each xml chunk ($string) need to be valid xml ?